# Sphinx autodoc : show-inheritance full name

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a hierarchy of modules with classes of the same name that subclass each other, e.g.

```py
# foo.py
class Box: ...
```

```py
# bar.py
class Box: ...
```

```py
# foobar.py
import foo, bar
class Box(foo.Box, bar.Box): ...
```

My template for classes is setup with `objname` as title so that links remain short.

```
{{ objname | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}
   :show-inheritance:
```

This results in the stub for `foobar.Box` to show the inheritance:

> Bases: Box, Box

I would like it to use the full name instead, i.e.:

> Bases: foo.Box, bar.Box

Is there a way to change the template used by `show-inheritance`?

I can change the title of the class template to `fullname` but this makes the documentation very verbose. I tried to implement my own extension with a hook to `autodoc-process-bases` but with no success: I get the list of base classes but I cannot control how they get printed.

Answer (score 1):

The `autodoc-process-bases` hook can in fact use strings rather than classes themselves. I found a solution defining my own sphinx extension:

```py
def process_bases(app, name, obj, options, bases):
    ambiguity = getattr(obj, "__ambiguous_inheritance__", ())
    for i, base in enumerate(bases):
        if base in ambiguity:
            bases[i] = ":class:`{}.{}`".format(base.__module__, base.__name__)
```

Then I can add an attribute `__ambiguous_inheritance__` to the classes of my choice and it will expand the ambiguous links to their full name.

```py
# foobar.py
import foo, bar
class Box(foo.Box, bar.Box):
    __ambiguous_inheritance__ = (foo.Box, bar.Box)
```